# Create Permission Without Checking URI Segment on Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, permissions

i've a **function** from my simple library and called on some controllers

```
$activeUrl = str_replace(base_url(),"",current_url());
erporate_acl::has_permission($activeUrl);
```

and then here is my library code, here the code try to matching current URI ($param) data from database :

```
public static function has_permission($param){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('acl_model');
    $user        = $CI->session->userdata('user');
    $arrPerms    = $CI->acl_model->permissions($user);
    $currentMeth = strtolower(str_replace("::", "/", $param));

    $result = "";
    if (!empty($arrPerms)) 
    {
        if (strpos($currentMeth,'edit') !== false || strpos($currentMeth,'view') !== false || strpos($currentMeth,'delete') !== false) {
            $str = preg_replace('#\/[^/]*$#', '', $currentMeth);
            $result = in_array($str, $arrPerms);
        }else{
            $result = in_array($currentMeth, $arrPerms);
        }

    }else{
        $result = false;
    }

    if ($result == false) {
        show_error("<font size='+1'>Sorry, You Don't Allowed to Access !</font><br><a href='".@$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'>Back to Previous Page</a>");
    }
}
```

the point of my script above is matching `in_array` if `in_array` return false then we got error message, else allowed to access the page

Is it possible to create permission without checking URI segment ?

Thank you and sorry for my bad English

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here exactly? Make it clear

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

`$this->router->class` to get the controller class that is being used;

`$this->router->method` to get the method being called;

`$this->router->directory` to get the directory in case you have sub-folders in your url being used.

This way you don't really need to check the url that's being used. You can just check the controller and method.

This is an agnostic way from the routes. In case you have something like:

- users/get/1
- user/marco-monteiro

ACL based on the uri segment can be hard in these situations. Using the methods I mentioned it gets easier.